# Guardar cadenas como recursos en strings.xml o en constantes estáticas, ¿hay algún criterio bien definido? ¿podemos definirlo?

Tags: android, string

Ante la posibilidad de guardar cadenas como recursos en `strings.xml` o como constantes estáticas quisiera saber si hay criterios bien definidos en [android](/questions/tagged/android).

Lo que he leído hasta ahora es que generalmente:

- se guardan como recursos en `strings.xml` las cadenas que se vayan a presentar en la interfaz,
- se guardan como constantes estáticas las cadenas que forman parte del funcionamiento interno del código (credenciales de la BD, tablas, etc).

**¿Existe realmente un criterio bien definido al respecto en alguna parte?**

**Si no existe ningún criterio, ¿podríamos formarnos alguno tomando en cuenta elementos bastante prácticos como la facilidad de portar, traducir, internacionalizar, aplicar estilos... a esas cadenas?**

Planteo la pregunta porque me parece importante que exista un criterio claro al respecto.

He leído algunas preguntas en StackOverflow en inglés como:

- [String.xml or Constants class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8380751/5587982)
- [android - strings.xml vs static constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16160047/5587982)
- [Where to store string values?In strings.xml or in constants class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428064/5587982)

Casi todas apuntan al criterio mencionado al principio de la pregunta. Considero importante que exista al respecto una respuesta bien elaborada en castellano que pueda ayudar a tomar decisiones al respecto.

Este es un ejemplo de mi código:

```
public static final String OL_TITULO = "<h2>" + CSS_RED_A + "OFICIO DE LECTURA" + CSS_RED_Z + "</h2>";
public static final String LA_TITULO = "<h2>" + CSS_RED_A + "LAUDES" + CSS_RED_Z + "</h2>";
public static final String VI_TITULO = "<h2>" + CSS_RED_A + "VÍSPERAS" + CSS_RED_Z + "</h2>";
public static final String HI_TITULO = "<h2>" + CSS_RED_A + "HORA INTERMEDIA" + CSS_RED_Z + "</h2>";
public static final String CO_TITULO = "<h2>" + CSS_RED_A + "COMPLETAS" + CSS_RED_Z + "</h2>";
```

Actualmente las cadenas están definidas como constantes estáticas. En este caso son constantes que se presentan como encabezados en la app. Las constantes como `CSS_RED_A` y `CSS_RED_Z` son para dar el color rojo a ese texto.

Hay constantes más largas como por ejemplo:

```
public static final String PADRENUESTRO = "Padre nuestro,~¦que estás en el cielo,~¦santificado sea tu Nombre;~¦" +
        "venga a nosotros tu reino;~¦hágase tu voluntad~¦en la tierra como en el cielo.~¦" +
        "Danos hoy nuestro pan de cada día;~¦perdona nuestras ofensas,~¦" +
        "como también nosotros perdonamos a los que nos ofenden;~¦" +
        "no nos dejes caer en la tentación,~¦y líbranos del mal. Amén.";
```

O constantes para mostrar mensajes de error:

```
public static final String ERR_CONEXION = CSS_RED_A + "¡ERROR! " + CSS_RED_Z + BR + "No estás conectado a internet." + BR +
        "En esta primera etapa de desarrollo la conexión a internet es necesaria para utilizar la aplicación. " +
        "En un futuro, D.M., implementaremos la posiblidad de utilizar la aplicación sin conexión.";
```

También hay constantes para usar en el código, por ejemplo esta, para establecer el tiempo de espera de peticiones `Volley`:

```
public static final int VOLLEY_TIMEOUT = 15000;
```

O esta para indicar la URL de la API:

```
public static final String URL_API = "https://www.example.com/api/vXXX/";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ambas pueden ser opciones para almacenar cadenas, el criterio para definir el uso de una u otra opción se puede determinar por las ventajas de una sobre otra, en el caso de recursos dentro del archivo `strings.xml` las grandes ventajas son:

Tienes la opción además de aplicar [**formato y estilo a los textos**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling).

```
<string name="bienvenida">Hallo, %1$s! feliz año %2$d , saludos!.</string>
```

Puedes [soportar diferentes lenguajes para tu aplicación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages).**

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Puedes definir arreglos de strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="string_array_name">
        <item>Gato</item>
        <item>Perro</item>
        <item>Pato</item>
        <item>Gallina</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Puedes definir ["Plurals": Strings de cantidad](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals):

> Los diferentes idiomas tienen distintas reglas de concordancia
>   gramatical con la cantidad. En inglés, por ejemplo, la cantidad 1 es
>   un caso especial. Se escribe “1 book” (1 libro), pero para las demás
>   cantidades se debe escribir “n books” (n libros). Esta distinción
>   entre singular y plural es muy común; sin embargo, en otros idiomas,
>   se hacen distinciones más detalladas. El conjunto completo compatible
>   con Android es zero, one, two, few, many y other

---

En realidad si deseas cadenas que no requieren las propiedades anteriores puedes optar en guardar cadenas como recursos en `strings.xml` o en constantes estáticas.

Answer (score 1):

El criterio bien definido es si el `String` puede ser sujeto de traducción o no.
Todas las respuestas, me parece, coinciden con eso.

Cuando el string no es un texto que vaya a ser traducido, entra en juego la convenciencia.

Una url, por ejemplo, puede estar definida como constante, pero también podría estar en un archivo de configuración, no hace a la clase (que la utiliza) en sí. Entonces una alternativa (que yo suelo usar) es ponerla en el strings.xml, pero tal vez otro lo ponga como constante, o en un archivo json o properties.

Por otro lado para un dato que hace al comportamiento o estado de una clase, no hay un beneficio por ponerlo en strings.xml. Al contrario, la clase queda innecesariamente acoplada a otro archivo. Y también se complica el uso, dado que para levantar el dato hay que tener el Context a mano y no siempre es el caso. Y también la lectura del código se vuelve más complicada (ejemplo: TAG vs R.string.clase_xxx_tag).